# Why is it that I can include a header file in multiple cpp files that contains const int and not have a compiler error?

Tags: c++, compilation, header, include

Let's assume that I have files a.cpp b.cpp and file c.h. Both of the cpp files include the c.h file. The header file contains a bunch of const int definitions and when I compile them I get no errors and yet I can access those const as if they were global variables. So the question, why don't I get any compilation errors if I have multiple const definitions as well as these const int's having global-like scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a `const` declaration at namespace scope implies internal linkage. An object with internal linkage is only available within the translation unit in which it is defined. So in a sense, the one `const` object you have in `c.h` is actually two different objects, one internal to `a.cpp` and one internal to `b.cpp`.

In other words,

```
const int x = ...;
```

is equivalent to

```
static const int x = ...;
```

while

```
int x;
```

is similar to

```
extern int x;
```

because non-`const` declarations at namespace scope imply external linkage. (In this last case, they aren't actually equivalent. `extern`, as well as explicitly specifying external linkage, produces a *declaration*, not a *definition*, of an object.)

Note that this is specific to C++. In C, `const` doesn't change the implied linkage. The *reason* for this is that the C++ committee wanted you to be able to write

```
const int x = 5;
```

in a header. In C, that header included from multiple files would cause linker errors, because you'd be defining the same object multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

From the current C++ standard...

> #### 7.1.1 Storage class specifiers
>
> 7) A name declared in a namespace scope without a storage-class-specifier has external linkage unless it has internal linkage because of a previous declaration and provided it is not declared const. **Objects declared const and not explicitly declared extern have internal linkage.**
>
> #### 3.5 Program and Linkage
>
> 2) When a name has **internal linkage**, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes in the **same translation unit**.

The preprocessor causes stuff defined in headers to be included in the current translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

When you do so, you create a separate `const` variable in each object file for every constant in the header. It's not a problem, since they are `const`.

Comment: So does each object file have it's own 'definition' so to speak

Answer (score 0):

Real reason: because `#define` is evil and needs to die.

Some usages of #define can be replaced with inline functions. Some - with `const` variable declarations. Since #define tends to be in header files, replacing those with `const`s in place better work. Thus, the "consts are static by default" rule.